# Prevent .zargo files to be opened as compressed files

Tags: nautilus, file-association

I installed Argo UML (http://argouml.tigris.org/) on my PC with Ubuntu 14. 04.

It's located in `/opt/argouml`. I've made a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/argouml` for `/opt/argouml/argouml.sh`. Also I've created a desktop file in /usr/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Argo UML
GenericName=UML Editor

Icon=/usr/argouml/icon/argouml.svg

Type=Application
Categories=Development;

Exec=argouml %F
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

Argo UML creates `.zargo` files for storing diagrams on file system. Ubuntu considers this file as Zip Archive and opens with Archive Manager. I tried to change the default application, and than it opens with Argo UML not only zargo files, but also zip archives. So I restored the default state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the following as `arguml.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="application/x-argo-uml-diagram">
    <comment>Argo UML diagram</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.zargo"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then open a Terminal and run

```
xdg-mime  install --novendor argouml.xml
```

This creates a new MIME Type `application/x-argo-uml-diagram` and associates it with `.zargo` files.

Now add the line

```
MimeType=application/x-argo-uml-diagram
```

to your5 .desktop file to let the system now that Argo UML can open `application/x-argo-uml-diagram` files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please update your answer with this extra information. I also added `application/x-argo-uml-diagram=argouml.desktop` line in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` to make ArgoUML open zargo files. And to set icon I used https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes